# Safest way to store a authentication token in a mobile web application

Tags: django, html, sencha-touch, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on a mobile web application and have finished up the authentication (server-side), but i am very unsure how to store the authentication token received from my REST service handling the transactions between the client.

It has raised following questions:

- Is it safe to use localstorage (HTML5) to store the token?
- Should the token be erased when the application is closed (if even possible)?
- Should the REST service generate a new token at every single login?

What are the best practices? I understand that there are other options when the application goes native instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot prevent a user from using a PC to request the token, that is the first vulnerability. Same goes for the request itself.

So the vulnerability chain is

1. Request
2. Store to variable
3. localStorage

If you still need more safety you can use the SCJS library to encrypt it before you send it to the localStorage (which is a human readable file in an open available folder).

Inside an app that is different as the localStorage is only available during the app session.